# UsingDirectivesMustBePlacedWithinNamespace enabled false but still showing stylecop error

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

In my solution StyleCopSettings has a Rule (UsingDirectivesMustBePlacedWithinNamespace) which is disabled but when I build the solution in release mode, I still see stylecop error saying Using directives must be inside the namespace.

```
  <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="UsingDirectivesMustBePlacedWithinNamespace">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a Stylecop settings file in the project to point to the one in the solution. This helped resolving the issue:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <StringProperty Name="LinkedSettingsFile">..\..\SolutionSettings.StyleCop</StringProperty>
    <StringProperty Name="MergeSettingsFiles">Linked</StringProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
</StyleCopSettings>
```